# How to get size of bounding box in Phaser 3, Spine?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

If i write `sprite.drawDebug = true`, it will show bouding box.

Bounding box in Spine 2D
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what exactly you need, it will be more or less difficult since this data is not exposed in a "user friendly" way *(as far as I know)*  here is the [link to the documentaiton](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/SpinePlugin.html#skeletonDebugRenderer__anchor)

**The SpinePlugin** uses the `sprite.drawDebug = true` flag to show many different parts of the spine data.
In this example you can see, how this parts a divided: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/spine/draw-debug-bounds#

[image: screenshot example]

> With the Buttons you can switch on and off the different parts

Depending on which group of boxes you need, you would have to access the data, similar as the plugin itself. (here is the link to the [plugin source code](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.51.0/plugins/spine/src/runtimes/spine-webgl.js) around lines 9936 ~ 10095 ). The data should be in the property `sprite.skeleton`  , but you would have to find the parts you really need.

**Update:**
if you are using physics and the physics bounding box is enough, like in this example: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/spine/arcade-physics-spine-body#

you could get the size of the bounding box with `image.body.width` and `image.body.height`, and you can alter it also with `setSize`.

[image: screenshot physics altered example]

Comment: Thanks you, so far does not work, but i will try

Comment: Setting `sprite.drawDebug = true`, where sprite is the spineObject, worked for me